# Form submission works with html but not javascript at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms, getelementbyid

I want to achieve that the user can search on the website and then filter his search results by clicking on a link (which triggers javascript) so he gets people instead of articles. In terms of database and PHP it works, but when I try to submit this code:

```
<form id="searchform" class="navbar-form" role="search" method="post" action="/search">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 300px;" placeholder="Search" name="searchterm" id="srch-term" value="<?php if(isset($searchterm)) { echo $searchterm; } ?>">
                      <div class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  </form>
```

... with this code:

```
function submit() {
  document.getElementById("searchform").submit();
}
```

this is what I use to communicate with my database initially, the url leads to a PHP function that returns the users. (works)
The following code only gets submitted with **HTML button**, but not with the link which will submit the form through javascript.

```
    $("#searchform").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url : "/search/people",
      data : form.serialize(),
      dataType : "json",
      success : function(data){
          if(data.length > 0) {
            console.log(data);
          } else {
            console.log('Nothing in the DB');
          }
      }
  }, "json");
});
```

I get no results in the **console** when I press the link, BUT with the search bar button (html) I get something in the console.

So what I want to do is with the second link in this code:

```
  <div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">sounds</a>
  <a id="people" onclick="submit()" href="#" class="list-group-item">people</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item">requests</a>
</div>
```

I will submit the javascript **that part is not working.**

Any suggestions on what I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example of your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/jonva/x99nxz0h/1/

It seems perfectly fine.

```
<form id="searchform" class="navbar-form" role="search" method="post" action="/echo/json">
  abc
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 300px;" placeholder="Search" name="searchterm" id="srch-term" value="">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>



$("#searchform").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var form = $(this);
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/echo/json",
     data: form.serialize(),
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
       if (data.length > 0) {
         console.log(data);
       } else {
         console.log('Nothing in the DB');
       }
     }
   }, "json");
 });
```

Comment: Does this help you? @veslav

Comment: No I actually forgot to put something in, I edited it maybe you understand what I mean now.

Comment: I'm sorry i still don't understand. Could you create a snippet?

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me, but I already found the solution. I had my id naming wrong, and the onclick needed to be something else. So I figured it out already.